# HAVING clause properties

Tags: sql, postgresql, having

I need help with this exercise where I have to translate properties from English into sql.

### Questions:

1. length has at least one 0

   ```
   Answer: MIN(ABS(length)) = 0
   ```
2. length has more that one value

   ```
   Answer: MIN(length) < MAX(length)
   ```
3. there are no nulls for length

   ```
   Answer: COUNT(*) = COUNT(length)
   ```
4. values of length are either positive or negative

   ```
   Answer: MIN(length) * MAX(length) > 0
   ```
5. length differs above and below zero by the same amount

   ```
   Answer: MIN(length) = -max(length)
   ```
6. all values of length are different

   ```
   Answer: COUNT(DISTINCT length) = COUNT(length)
   ```
7. only one of min(length) or max(length) is positive

   ```
   Answer: MIN(length) * MAX(length) < 0
   ```
8. length has one value or null value

   ```
   Answer: MIN(length) = MAX(length)
   ```

Are these correct? I'm not sure about #3, 5, 6 and 8 in particular.

Comment: #8 Looks fishy. Min(Null) = Null as will Max(Null). Equating Null to Null results in Unknown as opposed to True or False.

Comment: I think what #8 means is: that it has either one value or all nulls. Wouldn't  Min(Null) = Null return all nulls?

Comment: I think there is a typo in your answer to #4 -- what is `X`?

Comment: user640072: Not quite.  You can know if something IS null (meaning undefined/unknown), but you can't tell if two null's are equal.  So, this would be true: `MyNullField IS NULL`.  But this would not:  `MyNullField = NULL`

Comment: Awesome exercise! How do I donate money to this school?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. length has at least one 0

   ```
   Answer: MIN(ABS(length)) = 0
   ```
2. length has more that one value

   ```
   Answer: MIN(length) < MAX(length)
   or
   Answer: COUNT(distinct length) > 1
   ```
3. there are no nulls for length

   ```
   Answer: COUNT(*) = COUNT(length)
   ```
4. values of length are either positive or negative

   ```
   Answer: MIN(length) * MAX(length) > 0
   or
   Better Answer: Sign(MIN(length)) * Sign(MAX(length)) > 0

   -- Because, with large values of length, multiplying two of them
   -- together can give you an overflow.
   ```
5. length differs above and below zero by the same amount

   ```
   Answer: MIN(length) = -max(length)
   ```
6. all values of length are different

   ```
   Answer: COUNT(DISTINCT length) = COUNT(length)
   ```
7. only one of min(length) or max(length) is positive

   ```
   Maybe Wrong Answer: MIN(length) * MAX(length) < 0 (0 is not positive)
   or
   Answer: MIN(length) <= 0 and MAX(length) > 0

   -- IF: one must be positive and the other must be negative
   -- change <= 0 to < 0
   ```
8. length has one value or null value

   ```
   Wrong Answer: MIN(length) = MAX(length) -- null=null does not return true
   or
   Answer: COUNT(distinct length) <= 1
   ```

Comment: Not sure about 7. *must* one of them be positive, or *at most one*?

Comment: I think that one must be positive and the other must be negative.

Comment: @user640072 : The text doesn't lend itself to such an interpretation

Answer (score 0):

I would question #2.  You may have two identical length values.

For #3, I would not use the HAVING clause to check for non-nulls.  Same thing for #4.  HAVING is ***not*** the right place to be checking equivalency for each row against a scalar value.

#5 might have some problems worth wording.  Are you certain they mean min and max and not distribution?

#8 is oddly worded as well.  Null could be the value of length, or it could be absence of value.  It depends on how the query is formated.  Also, is there a requirement that you not use operators like `AND` & `OR`?

Also, NULL is treated as "unknown" with most database platforms.  Since it is unknown, it cannot be checked for equivalency against another value.  If you don't know what `Value1` is, you can't possibly know if it's the same as what's in `Value2`...

Comment: For #2, yes I could but that is not what it's asking. 
It doesn't care about the values from min() to max(), it just wants at least two different values, thus if min < max they must be different.
For #3,4, actually I'm required to use HAVING. 
For #5, I really don't know it's a very ambiguous question.
For #8, yeah I could use AND & OR. I think null means absence of value.

Comment: You could argue either way for NULL.  Academically it's an absence of value, in the real world it's an actual assignable value in a lot of popular databases and programming languages.  I find it easier to think of it as "unknown" because it precludes one from trying to measure it against a known value.  It simply can't be done.

For #2, I think the COUNT() approach is a better choice because you're not asking as much out of the query engine.  There's no real need to get two aggregates and do a scalar comparison, you really JUST want to know COUNT(DISTINCT...)